# Trouble while writing an resiseable vector with std::vector

Tags: c++

i'm a Brazilian beginner in c++ coding (apologize my poor knowledge in both things). I'm trying to write an .txt output file containing the positions of pixels i click with the mouse. I'm making use of opencv library, so thats a functional part of the code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>    
#include <vector> 
#include <fstream>    
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//declaration of vector and counter
int i = 1;
std::vector<int>vet_x(i);
std::vector<int>vet_y(i);


//the callback function
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {

        vet_x.resize(i);
        vet_y.resize(i);

        vet_x[i] = x;
        vet_y[i] = y;
        i++;

        cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Mat img = imread("lena.jpg");
    //Create a window
    namedWindow("Mouse Track Test", 1);
    //set the callback function for mouse event
    setMouseCallback("Mouse Track Test", CallBackFunc, NULL);
    //show the image
    imshow("Mouse Track Test", img);
    // Wait until user press some key
    waitKey(0);

    //the writing begins after the press of the key
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("points.txt");

    for (int j = 1; j <= vet_x.size(); j++)
    {
        cout << vet_x[j] << "," << vet_y[j] << endl;
        myfile << vet_x[j] << "," << vet_y[j] << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: the file write only the last clicked position!
But if i turn the "vet_x.reserve(1024);" line, it works well, but only for the y coordinates...

So, what is my mistake?

Comment: you should `push_back` into the vector instead of constantly resizing it.

Comment: You declare the vectors to contain only *one* element each. So when you write to any index except `0` you will write out of bounds. _Instead [*append*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) values to the vectors.

Comment: I don't see any "vet_x.reserve(1024);" line

Comment: `i'm a Brazilian beginner in c++ coding`  If you're a beginner, take the time to write a simple program with a `main` function so that you become familiar with using the various classes such as `std::vector`.  That is what any beginner and even experienced programmer would do.  Once you know how to use vector, then you apply it to your larger program.  Trying to learn how to use vector, and at the same time clutter up the learning with all sorts of matrix and mouse stuff isn't really productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vet_x.resize(i);
vet_y.resize(i);

vet_x[i]=x;
vet_y[i]=y;
```

You are **assigning** elements out of range, which is an undefined behavior. After `resize(i)` the last valid index is `i-1`.  [std::vector operator [] never insert elements in the container.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)

Rather just do

```
vet_x.push_back(x);
vet_y.push_back(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ array indexing is 0-based. Thus when you resize a vector `v` to size 1, and assign to `v[1]`, you're assigning to a non-existing item. This is Undefined Behavior.

To catch this kind of out-of-bounds indexing you can use the `at` method, which guarantees an exception. I.e., writing `v.at(i)` instead of `v[i]`.

However, you should simply use the `push_back` member function to add items to a vector. I.e., `v.push_back( x )`, where `x` is the value that you want to add. It can also be a good idea to use a single vector of 2D points, instead of one vector for x and one vector for y.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of adding variables into vectors is wrong. I suggest this:

```
struct Point
{
    int x, y;
    Point(int sx, int sy)
        :x(sx),y(sy)
    {        
    }
};

std::vector<Point> clickedPositions;

//the callback function
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        clickedPositions.push_back(Point(x,y));
    }
}
```

and while writing it into the file:

```
for(int j=0; j<clickedPositions.size(); j++)
  {   
   myfile << clickedPositions[j].x < <","<< clickedPositions[j].y <<endl;
  }
```

Comment: Actually he's using OpenCV so he could just use cv::Point or cv::Point2f.